# If you were the word "box" and a word beginning with a letter "m" to describe `\mbox` what might your English phrase be?

Tags: boxes, latex3, box

Note that English phrase "**mathematics blackboard bold**" is an example of a super-sequence of `\mathbb` which has the same meaning as `\mathbb`.

If you were the word "box" and a word beginning with a letter "m" to describe `\mbox` what might your English phrase be?

In the example below, the text "s.t." initialism of "such that" is wrapped in an `\mbox{s.t.}` environment.

```latex
\begin{alignat}{5}
  \max \quad        & z = &   x_1  & + & 12 x_2  &   &       &         && \\
  \mbox{s.t.} \quad &     & 13 x_1 & + & x_2     & + & 12x_3 & \geq 5  && \tag{constraint 1} \\
                    &     & x_1    &   &         & + & x_3   & \leq 16 && \tag{constraint 2} \\
                    &     & 15 x_1 & + & 201 x_2 &   &       & =    14 && \tag{constraint 3} \\
                    &     & \rlap{x_i \ge 0, i = 1, 2, 3}
\end{alignat}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I interpret `\mbox` as a shortening of `\makebox`, for a box that needs no additional attributes and doesn't have a visible frame.

Comment: I would use `\text` instead of `\mbox` here anyway. Or maybe a separate `equation*` environment for the first line (the objective function), and `alignat` for the constraints only.